# how to get two divs side by side like whatsappweb from two different pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Anyone can help me how to get two divs side by side like whatsapp web from different pages using javascript.I want to show them in a single page.Below is my code:

code of page1.html:

```
<div class="page1">
<p>hii</p>
<div>
```

code of page2.html:

```
<div class="page2">
<p>hello</p>
<div>
```

my php code:

```
<?php if($chat_topic_id==1) { 
    if(isset($_SESSION['customer_id'])!=""){
    $onclickEvent = "onclick='return showChatWindowApplication(".$chat_question_id.");'";
    }else{
$onclickEvent = "onclick='return ChatLoginModule(".$chat_question_id.");'";
                    }?>
 <div><a href="javascript:void(0);" <?php echo $onclickEvent;?>>
 <p><?php echo $chat_question_title;?></p></a></div>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with php

Comment: you need to fix your code first...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what youre looking for ?

```css
section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
}
div#page1{
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
}
div#page2{
    margin-left: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div id="page1"></div>
    <div id="page2"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: for example whatsapp in mobile is different from web

Comment: @priya hmm i  dont quite get what u maen. you mean to show page1 if its from desktop and show page2 if its from mobile ?

Comment: you want to show 2 files side by side for mobile and desktop? are you looking for somthing responsive or not? are you asking about design stuff (css and layout) or how to integrate 2 files into a main html page ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your example is false.

This would be the right example:

```css
.page1, .page2 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="page1">
<p>hii</p>
</div>

<div class="page2">
<p>hello</p>
</div>
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```css
iframe
{
width:49%;
float:left;
height:1000px;}
```

```html
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/"></iframe>

<iframe src="https://www.tutorialspoint.com/"></iframe>
```

using iframe you can show two different page in sigle window

Comment: actually i used divs for chat box

Comment: then you can use tabs why you are using as different pages